# Standardjs no-unused-vars while it's used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, standardjs

In my Typescript React project, I defined:

```js
export type NavState = { mounted: boolean }
```

and then in my component I used theme like:

```
import { NavState } from '../../models/nav'

class Nav extends React.Component<any, NavState> {
  state: NavState = {
    mounted: false
  }
}
```

but I got red underline for `NavState` in my import and it says:

```
'NavState' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)standard(no-unused-vars)
```

In my `package.json` I have this:

```
  "standard": {
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules/**",
      "**/__generated__/"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint"
    ]
  }
```

and my vs-code `settings.json` is like this:

```
{
  "standard.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "standard.enable": true,
  "standard.run": "onType",
  "standard.validate": [
    { "language": "javascript", "autoFix": true },
    { "language": "javascriptreact", "autoFix": true },
    { "language": "typescript", "autoFix": true },
    { "language": "typescriptreact", "autoFix": true }
  ]
}
```

Why Standardjs can't understand that I used a type alias? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import { NavState } from '../../models/nav'  //eslint-disable-line
```

**Notice the comment on the import line**.

Check the [docs](https://standardjs.com/#how-do-i-hide-a-certain-warning) for more.