# How i can get warning instead of error in ESLint for no-unused-vars?

Tags: eslint

How I can get a warning instead of an error while using ESLint?

I use ESLint `6.7.2` version with a plugin for babel and react.

This is my actual `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    },
    "settings": {
        "react" : {
            "version": "16.7.0"
        }
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment: You don't have anything in your rules object, did you *try* putting your desired config there?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know how to do it could you help me?

Comment: Did you consider reading https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've found the answer:

It enough to add a rule for `no-unused-vars`:

```
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
},
```

Also, restart the server.

Comment: Thanks. Note to others: I also had to restart the server for this to get applied.

Comment: Note for anybody using TypeScript, see this answer for guidance on how to configure this setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802057/eslint-configuring-no-unused-vars-for-typescript