# Eslint no-unused-vars error shows for used interface in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslintrc

I'm using Vue with Vue CLI and Typescript.
I imported interface from vuex file and used it for `mapState` type annotation.
But eslint shows me an error.

```
'State' is defined but never used. eslint(no-unused-vars)
```

Code

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import { State } from '@/store/index';

@Component({
  computed: mapState<State>({
    cards: (state: State) => state.user.cards,
  })
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
```

.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'quotes': ['error', 'single'],
    'semi': ['warn', 'always']
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
  }
};
```

What should I do not to see the eslint error?

Comment: Did you find the answer since you post this thread? I have the same thing that is weird...

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

EsLint default `no-unused-vars` has an bug, that reproduces like you explain. According to my source [1] it should be fixed by using `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` like so:

```
overrides: [
   // Fix no-used-vars when importing ts types in .vue files
   {
     files: ["*.vue"],
     rules: {
        'no-unused-vars': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error'
     }
  }
]
```

Source [2] is another question on same topic. There, my solution [1] is one option among others. In [2] and [3] it is said you need the `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` installed like so:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

### Source:

[1] https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript/issues/14

[2] [ESLint - Configuring "no-unused-vars" for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802057/eslint-configuring-no-unused-vars-for-typescript)

[3] https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/eslint-for-typescript/

Comment: Fixed the errors just by running the npm installation command! Thanks