# ESLint warns about unused function parameter type

Tags: typescript, eslint

Without bypassing the warning `no-unused-vars`, how can I fix this code for ESLint to not complain about `_`?

I thought renaming the variable to `_` would solve the issue.

```js
type ById = (_: any) => string

export const normalize = (byId: ById) => (acc: Record<string, unknown>, doc: { data: () => unknown }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [byId(doc)]: doc.data(),
})
```

```
2:14  error  '_' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
```

Comment: It's an issue with ESLint parsing the TS type. The rule itself is broken for TS code. There is a replacement. Let me find it

Comment: wouldn't this fix it? https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-vars#ignore-identifiers-that-match-specific-patterns

Comment: @Nishant it's a workaround. ESLint still parses and interprets the *type* as *a function* which is the core of the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [esLint - Configuring "no-unused-vars" for Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802057/eslint-configuring-no-unused-vars-for-typescript)

Comment: You need to install [this package](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) which extends the ESLint stuff and adds some TS specific rules. In particular, it has [`@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md) which is the fixed rules you can use.

Comment: The link in Nishant's comment has rotted. Here is the Wayback Machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20201112015712/https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-vars