# Eslint interfere to Typescript type declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

[image]

Hey, that's the code I am working with.

When I am declaring a type this error is shown.

So Eslint thinks that I have to use this var and, instead I am returning void.

To use
*// eslint-disable-line*
comment is not an option because I want to avoid unnecessary comments. Also I don't want to set it in Eslint configuration.

How should I overcome this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: What does you eslint config look like? [Does this help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802057/eslint-configuring-no-unused-vars-for-typescript)?

Comment: @Adam changing eslint config is not an option for me. But this issue is caused because of  "no-unused-vars" is not enabled.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a painting.

Comment: @RobertasAnkudovicius - you say you don't want to disable the rule, and you don't want to edit the eslint configuration, so I guess you're out of luck. If you don't want to fix your problem using the tools you have available, how do you expect to fix it? You want to disable lint in CI or during build or something? Maybe turn off your editors eslint warnings? Your two options are 1) edit eslint, or 2) use //eslint-disable

Comment: @Adam yes, you're right. My mistake was to think that there are only the way to disable all unused vars, but appears that there is a way to disable only args on type declaration. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

So I found a way to solve this issue. My mistake was to think that there is only the way to disable all unused vars, but appears that there is a way to disable only args on type declaration.

To disable only args you have to go to .eslintrc file and add rule:
*"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "args": "none" }],*