# How can I fix the eslint error saying a TypeScript props interface is not used when it's actually used?

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint

I have this component using AvatarProps as type for the props :

[image]

Here's the interface declaration:

```
export interface AvatarProps {
  userName: string;
  userLastName: string;
  userImg?: string;
  onPress?: Function;
  backgroundColorAvatar?: string;
  editMode?: boolean;
  onPressEdit?: Function;
  editButtonIcon?: string;
  backgroundColorEditButton?: string;
  textStyle?: TextStyle;
}
```

When running eslint, this error pops up :

```
5:15  error    'AvatarProps' is defined but never used
```

eslint is triggered on commit  with lefthook from a lefthook.yml file like so :

```
 pre-commit:
  parallel: true
  commands:
    lint:
      files: git diff --name-only @{push}
      glob: "*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
      run: npx eslint {files}
    types:
      files: git diff --name-only @{push}
      glob: "*.{js,ts, jsx, tsx}"
      run: npx tsc --noEmit
commit-msg:
  parallel: true
  commands:
    commitlint:
      run: npx commitlint --edit
```

What can I do to get rid of the error in a clean way?

Comment: Any previous research ?

Comment: Tried yarn lint --fix as recommended but it does not fix it. Found a post advising to create an .eslintrc file. There is this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802057/eslint-configuring-no-unused-vars-for-typescript but I think it's not applicable in my context since I use npx from lefthook.

Comment: Can you show how did you declared the type?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski    I just edited the original post.

Comment: You are missing some plugins in eslint config. Can you show it?

Comment: I'm actually using this library https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob/blob/main/README.md in which ESLint is pre-configured. Not sure where to configure eslint.

Comment: The project has a devDependencies though : "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change your component to this:

```
import React from 'react'
import type { AvatarProps, DimensionsType } from '../shared/types';

const Avatar: React.FC<AvatarProps> = ({
        userName,
        userLastName,
        userImg,
        onPress,
        backgroundColorAvatar,
        editMode,
        onPressEdit,
        editButtonIcon,
        backgroundColorEditButton,
        textStyle,
    }) => {
        return <>
           {/* Here your component implementation */}
        </>;
    };
```

that's a way to describe the types of a functional component at least is more clean and descriptive. Please notice `React.FC<YourType>` allows you to extend all the common props a functional component has, plus all `YourType` fields. This allows you to render children's components like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

// Yous an example type
export interface AvatarProps {
    userName: string;
    userLastName: string;
}

/**
 * A children component that doesn't render nothing but you can implement
 * whatever you want here
 */
const MyChildrenComponent = () => {
    return <></>;
};

const Avatar: React.FC<AvatarProps> = ({ userName, userLastName, children }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {children}
            <Text>{userName + ' ' + userLastName}</Text>
            {/* Here the rest of your component implementation */}
        </>
    );
};

const SomeParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Avatar userName="Something" userLastName="">
            {/* Notice here I can insert my own component as a children of Avatar component */}
            <MyChildrenComponent />
        </Avatar>
    );
};
```

this approach has several cons (you can read more about it [here](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/)) because basically you are typing the function and not his arguments (props) and the `children` argument is always implied even if you use it or not.

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments `React.FC` isn't needed actually you can implement your component without using it like this:

```
const Avatar: (props: AvatarProps) => JSX.Element = ({
    userName,
    userLastName,
    userImg,
    onPress,
    backgroundColorAvatar,
    editMode,
    onPressEdit,
    editButtonIcon,
    backgroundColorEditButton,
    textStyle,
}) => {
    return <>{/* Here your component implementation */}</>;
};
```

where `JSX.Element` is the return value of your component in this case (there are also different types you can use to type the return of a functional component, this is just an example)

Comment: I have never seen syntax like this. I'm pretty sure `React.Fc` is deprecated at this point.

Comment: it's not deprecated as you. can see here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/570f4d59b5414ffa4ca99ad67f9bee19d4cd3d89/types/react/index.d.ts#L517. This is only not needed. if you don't want to render a `children` in your component but I will update my answer to clrarify this