# Typescript ESlint: unused var error when using callback function with parameters

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-typings

I have a situation, demo code below:

```
       const callFnWithArgs = (callback: (a: string, b: number) => void) =>
       async (a: string, b: number): Promise<void> => {
          try { 
               await callback(a,b)
              }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
```

The code works fine, but I have ESLint unused vars property setup in the project. I receive error that a and b are unused-vars in line 1.

Any solution for this? Function signature changes are welcome.

Note:

1. I do not wish to disable/bypass the unused vars property globally or here.
2. I do not wish to use 'any'
3. I do not wish to remove the type so that it would infer 'any'

Comment: IDK if this works with ESLint but usually you would name them `_` and `__`.

Comment: @caTS it does not worked

Comment: There are no unused vars here

Comment: In the line 1. a and b are unused vars.

Comment: Those aren't even variables, those are parts of a type annotation

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković still facing the error on type annotation!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` instead of `no-unused-vars`.

If you need to override a config, here's how to do it !

```
"no-unused-vars": "off",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn"
```

Comment: But why? Can you please elaborate on the difference between no-unused-vars vs @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars. Are not both the same?

Answer (score 1):

see https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/

> How to Use
>
> ```
> // .eslintrc.cjs
> module.exports = {
>   "rules": {
>     // Note: you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
>     "no-unused-vars": "off",
>     "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn"
>   }
> };
> ```

Comment: You didn't enable `no-unused-vars`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler thanks, now correctly reproduced and explained

Answer (score 1):

try checking the following discussions
[ESLint - Configuring "no-unused-vars" for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802057/eslint-configuring-no-unused-vars-for-typescript)

there might be some eslint configuration issues